# How do I query this Firebase structure?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is my firebase real time database structure. I am unsure how to query this structure due to have used push() to create these objects.

The query I am trying to create is to find the player by the inviteCode.

```
var myUserId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
 
var inviteCodeEntered = this.state.inviteCode;

const findByInviteCode = firebase.database().ref('team).child(myUserId).child(players/{inviteCode}')
```

I assume i will need to loop through the list of players within that team. I will also like to note that i will retieve the inviteCode the user is looking to search by through the frontend of my app I'm quite new to firebase, I'm coming from a MySQL background so all help is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the orderByChild functionality

Kindly refer to this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#range-queries

Comment: hey! so i dont even have to consider the id that push() creates which each item ,if  i use OrderbyChild?

Comment: Yes you don't have to worry about that, it sorts by the attribute you are specifying. For eg, you can order here by fullName or inviteCode